# writing single column to .csv in R

Tags: r, csv

HI folks: I'm trying to write a vector of length = 100 to a single-column .csv in R.  Each time I try, I get two columns in the csv file: first with index numbers from the vector, second with the contents of my vector. For example:

```
MyPath<-("~/rstudioshared/Data/HW3")
Files<-dir(MyPath)
write.csv(Files,"Names.csv",row.names = FALSE)
```

If I convert the vector to a data frame and then check its dimensions,

```
Files<-data.frame(Files)
dim(Files)
```

I get 100 rows by 1 column, and the column contains the names of the files in my directory folder. This is what I want.

Then I write the csv.  When I open it outside of R or read it back in and look at it, I get a 100 X 2 DF where the first column contains the index numbers and the second column has the names of my files.

1. Why does this happen?
2. How do I write just the single column of data to the .csv?

Thanks!

Comment: Cannot reproduce this. Works fine for me.

Comment: did you use `write.csv(Files,"Names.csv",row.names = FALSE)` **after** you convert to data.frame?

Comment: cannot reproduce - with row.names = FALSE output writes to 1 column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Row names are written by `write.csv()` by default (and by default, a data frame with `n` rows will have row names `1,...,n`). You can see this by looking at e.g.:

```
dat <- data.frame(mevar=rnorm(10))

# then compare what gets written by:
write.csv(dat, "outname1.csv")

# versus: 
rownames(dat) <- letters[1:10]
write.csv(dat, "outname2.csv")
```

Just use `write.csv(dat, "outname.csv", row.names=FALSE)` and the row names won't show up.

And a suggestion: might be easier/cleaner to just just write the vector directly to a text file with `writeLines(your_vector, "your_outfile.txt")` (you can still use `read.csv()` to read it back in if you prefer using that :p).

Comment: I'm too much of a newbie for my upvote to show but thanks.  This worked like a charm, and I also appreciate the suggestion!

Comment: good! you should be able to "accept" the answer, btw (that'll prob earn you a badge or smthg too ~~)